# Creating a text translator with text file

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to have this program take a normal English sentence in one text box and with the click of a button convert it into a textese sentence.

Any word that can be shortened will be replaced with the words in a text file.

An example of a line in the text file is

> anyone,ne1

There are 52 lines (replacement words).

What would be the best way to approach this problem? Is a nested loop possibly a good route to take?

I don't have much experience and trying to learn the language more so open to trying all methods.

Below is what I have so far before I begin the coding process as I'm not really sure where to head from here. Only the words that are found within the text file will be replaced, so I think I'd use an If/Else statement that would ignore and leave any words not found alone.

```
Public Class frmTextese

Dim inputData() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Textese.txt")

Private Sub btnTranslate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTranslate.Click

    Dim english As Integer = 0
    Dim englishSentence As String = txtEnglish.Text

    Dim result() As String
    result = englishSentence.Split(englishSentence)

    Dim line As String
    Dim data() As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To (inputData.Length - 1)
        line = inputData(i)
        data = line.Split(" "c)
    Next

    'txtTextese.Text = 

End Sub

End Class
```

An image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e30d7f574ef27eb929f7a3097734f5fd

Answer (score 0):

Try this and have a look at the comments to get an idea of what is happening. I should add that strictly speaking, this site isn't a code writing service, but I can't help it sometimes. This also takes into account capitalization of words and common punctuation after the words. It's a bit quick and dirty, but for the basics, it seems to work ok.

```
Public Class frmTextese
    'create a new empty dictionary where we'll add the pairs of english and
    'textese words
    Dim englishToTextese As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Private Sub frmTextese_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'load textese dictionary to an array
        Dim filedata() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("k:\textese.txt")
        'Split each line into its elements and add to the dictionary
        For Each item As String In filedata
            Dim splitstring() As String = item.Split(","c)
            englishToTextese.Add(splitstring(0), splitstring(1))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function IsCapitalized(word As String) As Boolean
        'If the first character in the word is upper case then return true
        'else return false
        If Mid(word, 1, 1) = Mid(word, 1, 1).ToUpper Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function GetPunctuation(word As String) As Tuple(Of String, String)
        'If the last character in the word is a punctuation mark, return a pair of values which are :
        'the word without puctuation, and the punctuation. Else
        'return the word and an empty string
        Dim result As Tuple(Of String, String)
        If "!':;?/.,".Contains(word.Last()) Then
            result = New Tuple(Of String, String)(Mid(word, 1, word.Length - 1), word.Last)
        Else
            result = New Tuple(Of String, String)(word, "")
        End If
        Return result
    End Function

    Private Sub btnTranslate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTranslate.Click
        Dim textese As String = ""
        'split the text in the txtEnglish textbox into its component words including any punctuation
        Dim words() As String = txtEnglish.Text.Split(" "c)
        For Each englishWord As String In words
            'get the word and any punctuation following it as a pair of items
            'and store in punctResult
            Dim punctResult As Tuple(Of String, String) = GetPunctuation(englishWord)
            Dim texteseWord As String
            'store the first item (the word) in englishWord
            englishWord = punctResult.Item1
            'store the secont item (the punctuation or a blank string) in punctuation
            Dim punctuation As String = punctResult.Item2
            'If the english word is in the dictionary
            If englishToTextese.ContainsKey(englishWord.ToLower) Then
                'get the textesevertion
                texteseWord = englishToTextese(englishWord.ToLower)
                'if the original english word was capiutalized, capitalize the textese word
                If IsCapitalized(englishWord) Then
                    texteseWord = texteseWord.ToUpperInvariant
                End If
                'add the word to the textese sentence
                textese = textese & texteseWord & punctuation & " "
            Else
                'if the word isn't in the dictionary, add the original english word and its original state
                'of capitalization and punctuation to the textese sentence
                textese = textese & englishWord & punctuation & " "
            End If
        Next
        'store the new texteze sentence in the textbox
        txtTextese.Text = textese
    End Sub

End Class
```